# Clip satellite image to study area based on dropdown list location selection using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, clip, administrative-boundaries, dropdownlist

```
var statesDropdown = ui.Select({
  placeholder: 'Loading states...',
  disabled: true,
  onChange: onStateChange
});
updateStates();

var districtsDropdown = ui.Select({
  placeholder: 'First select a state',
  disabled: true,
  onChange: onDistrictChange
});

var panel = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [statesDropdown, districtsDropdown],
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('vertical')
});
ui.root.insert(1, panel);

function onStateChange(stateId) {
  var districts = India.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_1', stateId));
  updateDistricts(stateId, districts);
  addStateLayer(stateId, districts);
}

function onDistrictChange(districtId) {
    var district = India.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2', districtId))
                        .first();
    var region = India.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2',districtId));
    Map.clear();
    Map.centerObject(region, 9);
    Map.addLayer(region, {},districtId); 
}

function updateStates() {
  ee.List(India.aggregate_array('NAME_1'))
    .distinct()
    .sort()
    .evaluate(function(states) {
      statesDropdown.items().reset(states);
      statesDropdown.setPlaceholder('Select State');
      statesDropdown.setDisabled(false);
    });    
}

function updateDistricts(stateId, state) {
  // Before districts have loaded
  districtsDropdown.items().reset([]);
  districtsDropdown.setPlaceholder('Loading districts...');
  districtsDropdown.setDisabled(true);
  
  state.aggregate_array('NAME_2')
       .sort()
       .evaluate(function(districts) {
          // After districts have loaded
          districtsDropdown.items().reset(districts);
          districtsDropdown.setPlaceholder('Select District');
          districtsDropdown.setDisabled(false);
       });
}

function addStateLayer(stateId, districts) {
    Map.clear();
    Map.centerObject(districts, 7);
    Map.addLayer(districts, {}, stateId); 
}
```

`NAME_1` represent the State and `NAME_2` represent District.
The code first prompts the user to select a State and then a District within the previously selected State. After this I want to clip Sentinel-2 dataset to the selected District. The variable representing the satellite dataset must be outside the functions already mentioned here.
If `dataset = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")` is the variable, how will I call the district boundary and use it to clip `dataset`.

Link: https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/b13932fbae530607a0575a77e1d665e7

Comment: Your asset ``India`` is not shared. The better way to share GEE  code uses the **Get Link** button. Also before sharing the link make sure you have given access to assets by enabling *Any One Can Read* from the Assets tab.

Answer (score 1):

The dataset should be accessed inside the function `onDistrictChange` in the code.

https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/2847617923c964ad883c9ca896d84667

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-01-30')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE',20))

var visualization = {
  min: 0,
  max: 3000,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

var statesDropdown = ui.Select({
  placeholder: 'Loading states...',
  disabled: true,
  onChange: onStateChange
});
updateStates();

var districtsDropdown = ui.Select({
  placeholder: 'First select a state',
  disabled: true,
  onChange: onDistrictChange
});

var panel = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [statesDropdown, districtsDropdown],
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  },
  layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('vertical')
});
ui.root.insert(1, panel);

function onStateChange(stateId) {
  var districts = India.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_1', stateId));
  updateDistricts(stateId, districts);
  addStateLayer(stateId, districts);
}

function onDistrictChange(districtId) {
    var district = India.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2', districtId))
                        .first();
    var region = India.filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME_2',districtId));
    Map.clear();
    Map.centerObject(region, 9);
    Map.addLayer(region, {},districtId); 
    var composite = dataset.mean()
    var clipImage = ee.Image(composite).clip(region.geometry())
    Map.addLayer(clipImage, visualization, 'RGB'+districtId);
}

function updateStates() {
  ee.List(India.aggregate_array('NAME_1'))
    .distinct()
    .sort()
    .evaluate(function(states) {
      statesDropdown.items().reset(states);
      statesDropdown.setPlaceholder('Select State');
      statesDropdown.setDisabled(false);
    });    
}

function updateDistricts(stateId, state) {
  // Before districts have loaded
  districtsDropdown.items().reset([]);
  districtsDropdown.setPlaceholder('Loading districts...');
  districtsDropdown.setDisabled(true);
  
  state.aggregate_array('NAME_2')
       .sort()
       .evaluate(function(districts) {
          // After districts have loaded
          districtsDropdown.items().reset(districts);
          districtsDropdown.setPlaceholder('Select District');
          districtsDropdown.setDisabled(false);
       });
}

function addStateLayer(stateId, districts) {
    Map.clear();
    Map.centerObject(districts, 7);
    Map.addLayer(districts, {}, stateId); 
}
```

Comment: is it possible to perform the process outside the function ? that's what I was hoping for.

Comment: I don't think any solution for that, Give me more details of the application I will do my best.

Comment: I'm trying to find out how we can access the `region` variable within `onDistrictChange` function from outside the function.